# Using Cow in a generic struct

Tags: rust

The following code:

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

struct Hip<'a> {
    hip: Cow<'a, [u8]>
}

struct Hop<'a, T: ?Sized + 'a> {
    hop: Cow<'a, T>
}

fn main() {
    let it_be: Hop<[u8]> = [1, 2, 3];
}
```

Fails to build because "the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `T`".

Whereas expecting `T` to implement `Clone` (as follows):

```rust
struct Hop<'a, T: Clone + ?Sized + 'a> {
    hop: Cow<'a, T>
}
```

Fails to build because "the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `[u8]`".

How come `Hip`, which is using a `[u8]`, compiles, but not `Hop`?

Why does the compiler request `Clone` to be implemented for `Hop`'s `T`, but not for `Hip`'s `[u8]`?

[On the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e2fc38424f3867637b4d2642e177cbe5)

Comment: The error message is bad here. Check what trait `Cow` needs in its documentation. Also your initializer in main won't work.

Comment: I think the error message is fine, at least if we read all of it. I think it makes clear that `Cow` needs `ToOwned`, and that the specific implementation of `ToOwned` needs `Clone`.

Comment: In theory that makes sense, but how come the compiler complained `[u8]` was not implementing `Clone` even though there is a way to make it work (one example in the question, another in the answer)?

Comment: You are right, the recommendation should be to add an `ToOwned` trait bound, not a `Clone` trait bound. It's hard for the compiler to understand what's best in this particular case.

Comment: Ok thanks I'm updating the answer with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) says the type should implement `ToOwned`.
The following works:

```rust
struct Hop<'a, T: ?Sized + ToOwned> {
    hop: Cow<'a, T>
}

fn main() {
    let it_be: Hop<[u8]> = Hop { hop: Cow::Owned(vec![1, 2, 3]) };
}
```

About the error message: the compiler generates the implementation of `ToOwned` for every type implementing `Clone`. So when the trait `ToOwned` is missing, it suggests to implement `Clone`.

This is a mistake because some types have good reasons to implement `ToOwned`without implementing `Clone`. `[u8]` is one of them, hence `Hip` compiles. Whereas `Hop`'s `T` was not bound to `ToOwned`, so it fails.

Comment: The compiler recommends the `Clone` bound because `ToOwned` is implemented for all types that implement `Clone`, which is a pattern often used for "extension" traits. But the advice isn't good in this particular situation.

Comment: "*`[u8]` implements `Clone`*" -- does it? I don't see how it can -- cloning would result in another slice (since a clone results in something of the same type), but the resulting slice wouldn't have an owner. `[T]` does implement `ToOwned<Owned = Vec<T>>`, and the Cow docs page has an example of a struct owning a `Cow<[T]>`

Comment: Sorry, there must be something I misunderstood. Why does the `Hip` case work, if `[u8]` does not implement `Clone` and `ToOwned`?

Comment: I think I read too quickly the first comment: `ToOwned` is implemented automatically when `Clone` is implemented, but `ToOwned` can be implemented without `Clone`. Now I understand better, thanks.

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't need to start off with a `Vec<u8>`, e.g. `let it_be = Hop { hop: (&[1, 2, 3][..]).into() }` works fine. The `Cow` starts off referencing the slice, but calling `as_mut()` will copy that into a `Vec<u8>` (through `[T]`'s implementation of `ToOwned`)

Comment: Nice, I confirm it works https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9a36dddf77e578478f555e8e67ca2a39
However it relies on mechanisms that are quite implicit. I tend to prefer a more explicit way to write it. Unless it has an advantage over performance, at least theoretically?